# Opening an Activity from a class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-volley

I have created a class called `UserAuthentication` for setting up login and sign in. I am using volley to communicate with the database. 
 Everything works fine except that I cannot open the next activity when the operation is successful. 

I have tried this but nothing happens :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,NextActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Also, when I type `context.startActivity()` Android Studio prompts me to add `@RequiresPermission` but when i do add it, it gives me an error.

UserAuthentication Class -> SignUp() code :

```
    public void SignUp(String userName,String userSignUpEmail, String userSignUpPassword){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_SIGNUP,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            result = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            if(Objects.equals(result, "Sign Up Successful")){
                                Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).userSignIn(
                                        jsonObject.getInt("userId"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("userName"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("userEmail"));
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context,NextActivity.class);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("SignUpError",error.getMessage());
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("userName",userName);
                params.put("userSignUpEmail",userSignUpEmail);
                params.put("userSignUpPassword",userSignUpPassword);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestHandler.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

In my Activity where I call my class function :

```
signUpButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String userName = usersignUpName.getText().toString();
            String userSignUpEmail = usersignUpEmail.getText().toString();
            String userPassword = userpassword.getText().toString();
            String userConfirmPassword = userconfirmPassword.getText().toString();
            if(userPassword.equals(userConfirmPassword)) {
                 UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(SignUpActivity.this);
                 userAuthentication.SignUp(userName, userSignUpEmail, userPassword));
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Passwords do not match !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Share your full code.

Comment: @Danish I shared my code, please help me

Comment: @VirenJoshi what is the context here?

Comment: @AADProgramming the SignUpActivity, I pass it's context to my class constructor and make it a class variable

Comment: Can you provide the full code for the UserAuthentication class, particularly where you assign context

Comment: What happens if you try this: ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);

Comment: @tendai the casting to activity is redundant, as we can access it using context...  There's not error in the statements.. I just made an error in my PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no error in the `Intent` and in `startActivity()`. 
I was trying to access a string from the JSONObject in `SharedPrefManager` when I had not passed any in my PHP code. 
These statements works just fine -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(conext,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with passing Activity Context to your SignUp parameter.
as you know Intent is only work with Current Context of Activity.

**i.e**

```
UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(SignUpActivity.this);
                 userAuthentication.SignUp(activityContext ,userName, userSignUpEmail, userPassword));
```

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: can you share me a logs while clicking on Button? Plz.

Comment: and plz make sure if whole SignUp function is calling or not, also please put Log after calling Intent. if it reaching out there or not,.

Comment: there was an error in my PHP code, it is working now. thank you for helping though

Comment: Thanks Viren, Plz Upvote or Accept the Answer if you found it helpfull.